# Android SQLite, Creating tables without using constant variables? Possible?

Tags: android, sqlite

Every example uses constant table properties, instead of just writing the table property in the name. I know it is a better practice to do it this way but is it possible for just writing queries?

Example:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );  
    }
```

What I want

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL('CREATE TABLE "databasename" (' +
                "keyrowid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ' +
                "keyname" TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
                "keyhotness" TEXT NOT NULL);'
        );  
    }
```

Of course mine isn't correct in sytnax, because of the problems with ' and " . 
I couldn't find a way to make this work, is it possible or do we have to use constants?
Thanks!

Comment: It's one in the same thing. Constants are used to reduce chances of having any typo errors while writing any query. If you feel that you won't make any error then go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one in the same thing. Constants are used to reduce chances of having any typo errors while writing any query. If you feel that you won't make any error then go ahead and use it.

As far as the mentioned query is concerned use this

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tablename (keyrowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, keyname TEXT NOT NULL, keyhotness TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: doesn't the variables need to have ' or " around them?

Comment: here you are trying to create a table with certain column names not inserting any values, hence ' or " is not required.

Comment: read examples http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/ this will clear you up